# Съехал текст из хедера

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
я хочу, чтобы надпись была в хедере

```css
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #616261 0%, #000000 100%);
border: 3px solid #06EA61;
box-shadow: -2px -1px 15px #01D154;
width: 1855px;
height: 100px;
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>h4ker <span>t0ne</span></h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Что то не понятное. https://jsfiddle.net/jm3zbuc7/1/
Вот тут у меня ничего не сьезжает.

Comment: я хочу, чтобы надпись была в хедере

Comment: Всё ровно не понимаю, что вы хотите. Но я бы сделал так https://jsfiddle.net/nfj2v6sh/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h1` по умолчанию имеет отступ `margin`. Так как высота у блока фиксированная, то `margin` стоит обнулить.

```css
header {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #616261 0%, #000000 100%);
  border: 3px solid #06EA61;
  box-shadow: -2px -1px 15px black;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>h4ker <span>t0ne</span></h1>
</header>
```

Comment: спасибо большое!